# Laravel 7: How to match two tables column?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-7, eloquent-relationship

Please see my code first,

Measurement Table:

| id | customer_id | service_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 2 |  |

Controller:

```
$customer = Customer::findOrFail($id);
$ex = Measurement::where('customer_id', $id)->pluck('service_id');
    if(count($ex) == 0){
      $service = Service::where('status', 0)->get();
    }
    else{
      $service = Service::where('id', '!=', $ex)->where('status', 0)->get();
    }
```

In Measurement table, if a customer doesn't have any `service_id`  then `$service = Service::where('status', 0)->get();` this will pass in view file.
If a customer have a service_id, then in view file all services will pass except that `service_id`.

Can anyone suggest me a better way for this?

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
$customer = Customer::with('services')->where('customer_id', $id)->first();
$serviceRowCount = 0;
if ($customer->services->count() > 0) {
  $services = $customer->services->whereNotNull('service_id');
  $serviceRowCount = $services->count();
  
}

if ($serviceRowCount > 0) {
   $services = Service::whereNotIn('id', $services->pluck('service_id'))->get();
} else {
   $services = Service::where('status', 0)->get();
}
return view('test')->compact('services');
```

I am assuming that Customer has primary key as customer_id, has relation with Measurement model as services and service_id has default value as null.